# exclude special strings with regex

Tags: regex

I need to exclude the following string format

```
APXXXX.XXXX.XXXX
```

(X is an hex character A-F, a-f or 0-9). AP is fixed followed by 3 groups of 4 hex characters separated by a dot. The hex characters can be Capitals or small letters.

But other strings like

```
APLS1001
apcn5001
aplscha6
APUS4005
APLSC453
```

must match by the regex. There are no dots inside these strings.

Any ideas. Thanks in advance

I tried a lot but no good results.

Comment: Which regex flavor?

Comment: `^[Aa][Pp][A-Za-z0-9]{6}$` seems to match your desired set and exclude the unwanted form

Comment: OP didn't tell strings are all the time `AP[A-Za-z0-9]{6}$` long. He just tell how long is the exclude, so you make assumptions. @jhnc

Comment: @GillesQuénot actually that is precisely what they did: strings like (some examples)

Comment: OP are rarely very precise on sample input. Many times, more specific specs will come later ^^

Comment: @GillesQuénot consider my comment my attempt to elicit that clarification :-)

Comment: @GillesQuénot: `^[^.]*$` also satisfies the requirements

Comment: That one is good, yes. Should be accepted answer. I was trying something like this, but was on another thing. Minus, it match blank lines: https://regex101.com/r/iQxCSW/1

Comment: `^[^.]+$` is better

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I adpated your hints to [Aa][Pp][A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}.*

Comment: Now it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

I have tried making a regex pattern as below that may fully accomplishes your seniors:

```
^(?!AP[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}$)[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

A explanation for it:

`^` start of the string.

`(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead assertion. It's a non-capturing group that checks for a specific pattern but does not include it in the match. It's used to assert that a certain condition is not met. In this case, it checks for the absence of a pattern.

`AP` Literally "AP". This part of the pattern checks for the specific string "AP" at the beginning of the input.

`[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}` matches exactly four characters. It can be any character from the following set:
`0-9`: Digits 0 to 9.
`A-F`: Uppercase hexadecimal letters A to F.
`a-f`: Lowercase hexadecimal letters a to f.
`\.`: This matches a dot (period) character. Since a dot is a special character in regex, it needs to be escaped with a backslash to be treated as a literal dot.

`[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}` (repeated three times): This part is similar to the previous `[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}` but repeated three times. It ensures that there are three groups of exactly four characters each, separated by dots.

`$` This asserts the end of the string. It ensures that the pattern applies to the entire string, meaning that there are no characters after the third group of four characters and the final dot.

`[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match one or more alphanumeric characters (letters or digits).

`$` end of the string.

Edit: Added a detailed explanation of the regex.

Comment: I guess that someone clicked the down button because of the bad quality of the question (edited myself) and not so detailed  answer. Anyway (+1)

Comment: Explanation of this answer is better than the explanation of the problem in the question....  (But that's just a matter of taste ...)

Comment: @GillesQuénot Thank you for your response, i have added a detailed explanation for the regex. please let me know for any other concern.

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
^(?![aA][pP][[:xdigit:]]{4}\.[[:xdigit:]]{4}\.[[:xdigit:]]{4}$)\w+$
```

### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQxCSW/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string anchor |
| `(?!` | [look ahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions) to see if there is not: |
| `[aA]` | any character of: 'a', 'A' |
| `[pP]` | any character of: 'p', 'P' |
| `[[:xdigit:]]{4}` | any character of: hexadecimal digits (a- f, A-F, 0-9) (4 times) |
| `\.` | . |
| `[[:xdigit:]]{4}` | any character of: hexadecimal digits (a- f, A-F, 0-9) (4 times) |
| `\.` | . |
| `[[:xdigit:]]{4}` | any character of: hexadecimal digits (a- f, A-F, 0-9) (4 times) |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string anchor |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string anchor |